# From a single row to mulitple columns in Python

Tags: python, format

How do I turn a list of numbers in to equal columns, in python..

```
import itertools

f= open('combinations.txt','w')
numb = [1,2,3,4,5,]
it = itertools.combinations(numb,5)
for x in it:
    f.write(str(x))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Your imports suggests that you want to create an Excel-file, however your code under it is writing the output into a text-file. Could you please elaborate what your end goal is here? Also please be specific of what part you're stumbling with, so that we can more easily help you.

Comment: I just didnt take it out.. Ignore Excel.. I just want to the format to print out multiple columns in a text file.. I plan to expand the solution later and I have already found that excel cant handle the array.